# Any hint about how Slice<T> is implemented in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

I'm learning Swift through Apple documentation and WWDC Sessions' videos and I was wondering about how `Slice<T>` is implemented.. I can't find much information in the official docs and I've understood that when you get a slice from an array through subscripting you actually get an object that points within the array.. I've seen also some code snippets that pass a slice to an array initialiser to create a new array with the slice elements, but that initialiser is not documented in the Swift Reference Doc..

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Swift "header"-file? When no, it can be really helpful with questions like this. In Playground type `import Swift` and then command-click on "Swift" and search what you need (`struct Slice<T>` for example).

Comment: You're right, I've didn't think about that since I've not yet subscribed to the iPhone developer program and so I can't code in Swift yet. At present time I only studied swift, next week I'll start coding and I'll surely try Playground! Thanks!